# Where should I configure code generation in NPM packages?

Tags: java, node.js, npm, code-generation, package.json

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix) and [Jsonix Schema Compiler](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix-schema-compiler) and I'm trying to figure the canonical way the Jsonix Schema Compiler should be integrated in NPM `package.json`.

The [`jsonix-schema-compiler`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonix-schema-compiler) NPM package provides a Java-based tool for code generation. If the `jsonix-schema-compiler` is installed as dependency then it can be used to generate XML<->JS mappings. The invocation is as something like:

```
java -jar node_modules/jsonix-schema-compiler/lib/jsonix-schema-compiler-full.jar
    schema.xsd
```

This generates a JavaScript file like `Mappings.js` which is basically a part of module's code.

Ideally, `jsonix-schema-compiler` invocation above (`java -jar ...` and so on) should be executed during the module build. But it must be executed *after* modules dependencies are installed (otherwise `node_modules/jsonix-schema-compiler` will be missing).

**My question is - where should I canonically configure code generation in NPM packages?**

Right now I'm doing it in the `postinstall` scripts, something like:

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "jsonix": "x.x.x",
        "jsonix-schema-compiler": "x.x.x"
    },
    "devDependencies" : {
        "nodeunit" : "~0.8.6"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall" : "java -jar node_modules/jsonix-schema-compiler/lib/jsonix-schema-compiler-full.jar schema.xsd",
        "test": "nodeunit src/test/javascript/tests.js" 
    }
}
```

However having read [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts):

> tl;dr Don't use install. Use a .gyp file for compilation, and
>   prepublish for anything else.
>
> You should almost never have to explicitly set a preinstall or install
>   script. If you are doing this, please consider if there is another
>   option.

I am now confused if `postinstall` is also OK.

All I want to do is to be able to execute a certain command-line command *after* dependencies are installed but before other things (like tests or publish). How should I canonically do it?

Comment: I think you are supposed to avoid `install` scripts all-together; I also think you fall into that group that is doing things you almost never have to do - when you write a cross-language tool you have to make some assumptions. I think the main purpose for that warning is that someone may be installing your package as a dependency, if every dependency abuses the package install scripts think about what that means on dependency graph...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not quite sure what would that practically mean for me. Use `.gyp`? Don't people generate code in NPM packages at all?

Comment: I'm not certain either, that's why it was a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I understand, thank you. :) Let's see if someone would enlighten us.

Answer (score 2):

Typically people are running things like coffeescript-to-javascript compilers, Ecmascript 6->5 transpilers, and minifiers as a build step, which is what it sounds like you're doing.

The difference between doing it pre-publish and post-install is that a prepublish script is probably going to be run in your checked-out directory, so it's reasonable to assume that `java` is available and various dev-dependencies are available; while the post-install script would be run after every install, and will fail if java (etc.) is not available, as on a minimalist docker image.  So you should put your build step in a prepublish or similar script.

Personally what I like to do is define a script 'mypublish' in package.json that ensures all tests pass, runs the build, ensures build artefacts exist, and then runs `npm publish`.  I find this more intuitive than `prepublish` which is meant to be used as an "I'm about to publish" hook, not a "do the build before publishing".

Here is a package.json that uses this setup: https://github.com/reid/node-jslint/blob/master/package.json and here's the Makefile with the `prepublish` target: https://github.com/reid/node-jslint/blob/master/Makefile

Let me know if you have more questions; I'm kind of rambling because there are many legitimate ways to get it done-- as long as you avoid `postinstall` scripts. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer! *Typically people are running things like coffeescript-to-javascript compilers, ... as a build step, which is what it sounds like you're doing.* Almost, but not quite. Minifying etc. is not *essential* in the build in the context which you describe. That is, things will work (are testable etc.) without minfying or transpilling. In my case I generate a part of the module's code which is essential. You can't even test without this generation. So it's not like a "nice-to have befor publish" which is why I don't feel like `prepublish` is the right place...

Comment: But I think now I understood why `postinstall` is evil. :) It really runs when someone install your module which is not what I want. I just want a build step. `mypublish` as you rpopose it makes sense. What would make even more sense is some kind of a build lifecycle (like Maven has it), then I'd know where to put my things. Thank you for the input! I'll leave the question open for a while to see if there'll be more ideas.

Comment: By the way did you consider using these `.gyp` files `node.js` documentation mentions? https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: @lexicore - the `binding.gyp` file is designed to support building of C/C++ addons across Windows/Unix platforms, so it is probably not the easiest way to run a java build step (although it can run arbitrary shell commands).